# How do I find closest locations for each location in a list from a dataframe of unique locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geopy

What I have is a list of city + state locations like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

city_state = [
    ['Austin, Texas', 30.264265060424805, -97.74750518798828], 
    ['San Marcos, Texas', 29.882080, -97.939987], 
    ['Denver, Colorado', 39.7392364, -104.984862] 
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(city_state, columns=['Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
```

I also have a csv file that I read in as a Dataframe of locations that looks like this:

```py
data = [
    ['San Antonio, Texas', 29.425171, -98.494614],
    ['Oklahoma City, Oklahoma', 35.468491, -97.521263],
    ['Fort Collins, Colorado', 40.588970, -105.082458],
    ['Salt Lake City, Utah', 40.758480, -111.888138],
    ['Springfield, Massachusetts', 42.102051, -72.585762],
    ['Hartford, Connecticut', 41.764582, -72.6908547]
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
```

What I want to do is divide all these locations between `city_state` list so there are no duplicates and each "city_state" element has a list of "locations" that are closest to the "city_state" element. Plus I would also like to set a max radius of how far the "location" can be from "city_state" element. For example, if "location" row is more than 100 miles away from every "city_state" then it will be excluded.

So in short I want the result to be something like this:

```
{
    'Austin, Texas': [...], 
    'San Marcos, Texas': ['San Antonio, Texas', ...], 
    'Denver, Colorado': ['Fort Collins, Colorado', ...]
}
```

What I have found so far is how to do that to match only the closest location to each "city_state" element but I want to divide the whole list of locations between the "city_state" elements with a maximum radius limit.

If my explanations were unclear or something is missing please let me know.

**Edit****
I did find a solution that wouldn't have df2 duplicates between df1 locations but I don't think it's a very clean one and could probably be improved on.

What I have:

```py
def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # Convert coordinates to radians
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

    # Haversine formula
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    radius = 3958.8  # Radius of the Earth in miles
    distance = radius * c
    return distance

max_radius = 100

result = {}
closest_locations_x = {}
for _, city_row in df1.iterrows():
    city_name = city_row['Location']
    city_lat = float(city_row['Latitude'])
    city_lon = float(city_row['Longitude'])
    closest_locations = {}

    for _, location_row in df2.iterrows():
        if location_row['Latitude'] != 'Not Found' or location_row['Longitude'] != 'Not Found':
            location_name = location_row['Location']
            location_lat = float(location_row['Latitude'])
            location_lon = float(location_row['Longitude'])
            distance = calculate_distance(city_lat, city_lon, location_lat, location_lon)

            if distance <= max_radius:
                if location_name not in closest_locations_x:
                    closest_locations[location_name] = distance
                    closest_locations_x[location_name] = distance
                else:
                    if distance < closest_locations_x[location_name]:
                        result = {key: [value for value in values if value != location_name] for key, values in result.items()}
                        closest_locations[location_name] = distance
                        closest_locations_x[location_name] = distance

    result[city_name] = list(closest_locations.keys())
```

result:

```py
{'Austin, Texas': [], 'San Marcos, Texas': ['San Antonio, Texas'], 'Denver, Colorado': ['Fort Collins, Colorado']}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get your point. Maybe a table and clear output will help us to figure out

Comment: I would be happy to make the post more clear but I don't really understand what you mean by a table and clear output. I have a table for the locations in the post, and the output is a divided list of locations between "city_state" elements. I have edited the post to change naming of things to make it less confusing, does that help? @PTQuoc

Comment: You need to give some type of structure (dataframe?) with the city states and their corresponding longitude/latitude.

Comment: You need to further clarify your problem and question.  This can best be done by providing a sample oif the input data you have to work with, the code attempt made and a sample of the expected output that would result from your sample data

Comment: I have changed the table with dataframe and an answer with what I expect from that data. The real data is way bigger but this should show what I want to do. @itprorh66

Comment: How do you define distance?  Degrees Lat, Lon, Nautical Miles, miles, meters???

Comment: Distance of what? I have Lat and Lon for each location in df1 and df2 dataframes. What I want to do is divide the locations from df2 between df1 locations using Lat and Lon to decide which df2 location is closest to which df1 location. So the final result will be df1 locations with a list of df2 locations divided under each location. @itprorh66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the dataframes you provided, here is one way to do it with `GeoPy` [distance](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) function, `Python` built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class from the standard library's collections module:

```py
from geopy import distance
from collections import defaultdict

# Compute distance between all cities and each capital city
distances_between_cities = {}
for city, other_lat, other_lon in zip(
    df2["Location"], df2["Latitude"], df2["Longitude"]
):
    distances_between_cities[city] = {}
    for city_state, lat, lon in zip(df1["Location"], df1["Latitude"], df1["Longitude"]):
        if (
            d := distance.distance((lat, lon), (other_lat, other_lon)).miles
        ) <= max_radius:
            distances_between_cities[city][city_state] = d

# Remove duplicates
distances_between_cities = {
    k: min(v, key=v.get) for k, v in distances_between_cities.items() if v
}

# Get final results as dictionary with capital cities as keys
# and list of cities as values
closest_locations = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in distances_between_cities.items():
    closest_locations[v].append(k)
closest_locations = dict(closest_locations)
```

Then:

```py
print(closest_locations)
# Output

{'Denver, Colorado': ['Fort Collins, Colorado'],
 'San Marcos, Texas': ['San Antonio, Texas']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really like the cleanliness of this. But it has one problem. I have changed the original post to reflect the problem and create a better test scenario and the answer I am expecting. I also found a solution myself but it is kind of scrappy and I do prefer your solution. Basically, I want one df2 location to be in only one df1 location list (only for the closest one). For example in the updates post I have San Antonio, Texas under San Marcos, Texas but not under Austin, Texas because it's closer to San Marcos. Your code would put it in both. @Laurent

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer accordingly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the haversine formula to calculate the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes. This can be used to calculate the distance between two locations. You can then iterate over each location in `city_state` and for each location in `df2`, calculate the distance between them. If the distance is less than or equal to the maximum radius, you can add that location to the list of closest locations for that `city_state` element.

Here's an example code snippet that might help you get started:

```
from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, atan2

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    R = 6371 # Earth radius in km
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    return R * c

max_radius = 60 # maximum radius in miles
max_radius_km = max_radius * 1.60934 # convert miles to km

result = {}
for city_state in city_state:
    city_state_name = city_state[0]
    city_state_lat = city_state[1]
    city_state_lon = city_state[2]
    closest_locations = []
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        location_name = row['Location']
        location_lat = row['Latitude']
        location_lon = row['Longitude']
        distance = haversine(city_state_lat, city_state_lon, location_lat, location_lon)
        if distance <= max_radius_km:
            closest_locations.append(location_name)
    result[city_state_name] = closest_locations
```

This code calculates the distance between each `city_state` element and each location in `df2` using the haversine formula. If the distance is less than or equal to `max_radius_km`, the location is added to the list of closest locations for that `city_state` element. The final result is stored in a dictionary where the keys are the `city_state` elements and the values are lists of closest locations.

I hope this helps! If I'm wrong I am very sorry as I am still a beginner.

Comment: This is doing most of the job, I reached a similar point using chatgpt to guide me. The only problem with this one is that I would also like to not have duplicates. For example, If I changed Boston, Massachusetts with San Marcos, Texas. Then San Antonio would be in both lists but I would like it to be only in one list and in a one that it was the closest to. But thanks a lot for your answer!